# Height is ambiguous using Readable Content Guides and flexible thumbnail

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a video thumbnail (an `UIImageView`) and I want it to have a flexible size instead of a fixed width and height (how it was before). It needs to be flexible because I'm adding leading and trailing constraints between the thumbnail and the layout anchors of the [`readableContentGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622644-readablecontentguide) property of the content view of the cell.

So, I applied a ratio for the thumbnail height anchor to define the height using its width:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    videoThumbnailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 30),
    videoThumbnailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: readableContentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
    videoThumbnailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: readableContentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
    videoThumbnailView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoThumbnailView.widthAnchor, multiplier: VideoThumbnailRatio.plusOne.rawValue),
])
```

The thumbnail position and size is correct but the rest of the content has a wrong height:

[image: Thumbnail with ambiguous height]

[image: Constraints of the Thumbnail with ambiguous height]

[image: Constraints of the content with ambiguous height]

The rest of the **content constraints** are setup like this:

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.configure(distributon: .fill, alignment: .fill, axis: .vertical, spacing: 5)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(stackView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoThumbnailView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoThumbnailView.leadingAnchor),
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoThumbnailView.trailingAnchor),
])

stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(subtitleLabel)

let buttonsStackView = UIStackView()
buttonsStackView.configure(distributon: .fillEqually, alignment: .fill, axis: .horizontal, spacing: 10)
buttonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(contentSyncProgressView)
buttonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(myListOptionsView)
buttonsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(buttonsStackView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    buttonsStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.centerXAnchor),
    buttonsStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    buttonsStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
    buttonsStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 238),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsStackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20)
])
```

If I force a fixed **height** value to the thumbnail, then everything goes well:

[image: Thumbnail with no ambiguous height]

[image: Constraints with no ambiguous height]

**How can I avoid setting a fixed height for the Thumbnail and get the layout with no ambiguity?**

## UPDATE:

Demo project: https://github.com/ricardopereira/ThumbnailLayoutIssue

Comment: Since Xcode 9 there are aspectRatio-constraints that should help you with exactly this problem. Did you look into those?

Comment: @RobinBork No, I did not. I'll investigate. Thanks

Comment: @RobinBork No success. I added a demo project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always apply your constraints to a cell's `contentView` instead of the cell itself.

Following this, in your example you should replace `layoutMarginsGuide` with `contentView.layoutMarginsGuide`.

You should also set your `stackView`'s `distribution` to `fill`